# trying to have the user select 1-3 they can keep on looping and clicking them to get the if statement if they click 4 they go to the next menu

Tags: python-3.x

def cSelection():

while Selection < 4:
Selection = int(input())

```
  if Selection == 1 :
    print('Processing...')
    print('Oxygen levels are normal')
  elif Selection == 2:
    print('Processing...')
    print('Fuel levels are at medium capacity')
  elif Selection == 3:
    print('Processing...')
    print('Food is running low, request for new shipment')
  elif Selection == 4:
    print('Processing...\n')
    print('Here are a list of other topics')
    print('1 Lets be friends')
    print('2 Hows my singing?')

  return Selection
```

return_value = cSelection()

Comment: what's the question?

Comment: Where should my while function be? Also am I using it in the correct way or is this just a syntax issue. I want to be able to select 1, 2 or 3 and have it give the printed value but then  I can hit another number to have it loop or press 4 to get to the next selection .